# Silverlight MVVM Listbox binding

Tags: data-binding, silverlight-4.0

I have a listbox that I am binding to an obsevable collection ItemsSource="{Binding SearchItems} of search results which works great.  However, here is my problem.

1)  User enters a search term
2)  User scroll down the list of seach results to say the middel or the bottom of the list.
3)  User then enters a new search term without scrolling back to the top of the list
4)  When the new search results load the scroll control stays in the middle of the results listbox.

I can't quite figure out how to reset the scroll bar back to the top with each new search.  I didn't write the original code so I'm having difficulty figuring out what to look for.  Anyone have any suggestions or where to look?

```
 <localControls:AlternatingRowListBox ItemsSource="{Binding SearchItems}"
                                                         Name="ListBoxSearchResults"
                                                         BorderThickness="0"
                                                         ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource FoodSearchResultItemContainerStyle}"
                                                         AlternatingItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource FoodSearchResultAlternatingItemContainerStyle}"
                                                         HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
                                                         ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                                                         Margin="20,20,10,0"
                                                         Grid.Row="0"
                                                         ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
                                                         KeyUp="ListBoxSearchResults_KeyUp">
                        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <ContentControl HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                                                VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                                HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
                                                VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch"
                                                Content="{Binding Converter={StaticResource TemplateSelector}}" />
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    </localControls:AlternatingRowListBox>
```

Thanks,

Rhonda

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the ScrollIntoView method in ListBox. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.listbox.scrollintoview(v=VS.95).aspx.

Set the object to first object in the itemsource bound to the listbox.